ERR_CERT_REVOKED only on Smartphones (connection is not secure)
My website, which has been running smoothly for more than a year, started having issues as of today. While I can access it without any problems from my computer, when I try to access it from my phone, it gives a 'connection is not secure' warning. (NET::ERR_CERT_REVOKED).
I'm in the moment of troubleshooting the issue through trial and error, I deleted the content of the website and used PHP to print('text').
Here is the link to the page: https://t.ly/vdhmu
I contacted the host service and discussed the issue. I asked if there was a problem with the SSL. They said the issue might be related to the website's source code. Therefore, I temporarily deleted the website's content.

Are you sure your problem is in any way related to PHP or HTML?

I can't access that site using my desktop browser either. Interestingly, different "ssl checker" services give me different results - some say, everything was okay, whereas f.e. https://www.sslchecker.com/sslchecker and https://globalsign.ssllabs.com/analyze.html?d=pamiratarim.com report issues with the certificate chain, resp. that the certificate for pamiratarim.com had been revoked.

The phones are correct, the certificate is revoked - as can be clearly seen from this SSLLabs report:

As to why the certificate was revoked is unknown. Maybe the site is insecure and leaked the private key, in which case someone might have reported this so that the certificate got revoked.
As to why browsers on computers don't complains but apps do: revocation checks in many browsers are kind of broken for years.
What you need to do: get a new certificate with new private key. You cannot continue to use the existing certificate even if you change the source code of your site.
